# Understanding translationX() from right to left and displacement

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-animation

I have an animation view with a dust can and a cover, and I want to make it move from right to left in case the device's direction is (RTL). But, it's just from left to right in both conditions. If anyone can help me find my error.
(db = 0f)

```
override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator) {
                    var displacement = 0f
                    displacement = if (isLayoutDirectionRightToLeft) {
                        dp + 40
                    } else {
                        -dp * 40
                    }
                    dustin!!.translationX = displacement
                    dustin_cover!!.translationX = displacement
                    dustin_cover!!.animate().translationX(0f).rotation(-120f).setDuration(350)
                        .setInterpolator(
                            DecelerateInterpolator()
                        ).start()
                    dustin!!.animate().translationX(0f).setDuration(350).setInterpolator(
                        DecelerateInterpolator()
                    ).setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
                        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator) {
                            dustin!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            dustin_cover!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        }

                        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {}
                        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {}
                        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator) {}
                    }).start()
                }
```

....................

Comment: Did you try to log the `isLayoutDirectionRightToLeft` value? So you know whether it goes in the correct if/else branch.
What is `-dp * 40`? Can't it be `dp - 40` same as the + branch?

Comment: `(db = 0f)` Is this a typo and did you mean `dp = 0f` ?
If dp is 0 then `-0 * 40` will result in `0` so your displacement will be `0`

Comment: Thanks for interest, it was my problem, i forgot to add the "Boolean" value of layout direction in strings_rtl.xml
-- Yes, (dp = 0f), but the sign (-/+) in displacement value is for the direction not the value itself.

Comment: Ok, great you found it! You can write an answer so people who come here who have a similar question can see how you solved it and mark it as solved with a checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it, the code sample has no problems.
The sign (-/+) before the (db=0f) value is for directions (+ RTL), (- LTR).
The problem was the "Boolean" value of (isLayoutDirectionRightToLeft), i added it in (strings.xml) with the value false, but not in the (strings_rtl.xml)

```
<bool name="is_right_to_left">false</bool>
<bool name="is_right_to_left">true</bool>
```

Comment: I would suggest putting this boolean value in a `values.xml` file. Having a boolean value in a file named `strings` can be a bit confusing.

Comment: @miva2 -- I agree with you, but i wanted to make more sense to make it understandable and put it with translated string from (ltr to rtl)